# how to send an ajax request on clearing text box using jquery typewatch?

Tags: jquery, typewatch

Hi I use jQuery typewatch plugin to send an ajax request when the user stops typing in the text box. If the user enters something the result will be filtered based on that. if the user clears out the text box, i want to load the whole result how do i do that?

I tried setting the captureLength to 0, even tried to set the minTextLength on the plugin to 0. but it did not work. Here is an example which works as i want https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary fix, i am calling the keyup() event on the text box and if the text box value is empty i am calling the ajax load once again which will load the full data.

Any other better solution welcome.. :)